# Need help to get DataColumn of a DataTable

Tags: c#

I want to get a column with a given name into a DataColumn object so that I can iterate over the rows of that column. My code is given below. What replacement do I make in the line marked pseudocode ?

I guess you can safely ignore all this code and read the main() method code right away. Specifically, go to line -

```
DataColumn dc = getColumn("YourColumnName"); //PSEUDOCODE
```

The code is -

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ST_54125473205c4f38b466c43a15bc9d79.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = null;
            DataRow row = null;
            string strMsg = null;

            oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["myADO_Recordset"].Value);

            foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                DataColumn dc = getColumn("YourColumnName"); //PSEUDOCODE

                    var field1 = dc.ColumnName;
                    MessageBox.Show(field1);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [DataTable.Columns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx)

> Gets the collection of columns that belong to this table.

and use the [string indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fyswbf.aspx)

> Gets the DataColumn from the collection with the specified name.

So something like

```
DataColumn dc = dt.Columns["YourColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Column` name use `Columns property` in your `DataTable` instead of getting the `Rows`, like:

```
 foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
 {
     String field1 = dc.ColumnName;
     MessageBox.Show(field1);
 }
```